# Display phone number or email on home screen when phone locked?

Tags: iphone, ios

A friend recently lost her iPhone (running iOS 7.1.2). Thankfully, someone found it before the screen turned itself off and go through her list of contacts,, and she got her phone back; Otherwise, the person wouldn't have been able to get into the phone because of the pin number that locks the phone.

I remember that on a Blackberry, it was possible to display an email or phone number on the home screen even when the phone was locked. Can an iPhone running iOS 7 be configured likewise?

[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can trigger that using Find My iPhone or on icloud.com. Just put it into Lost Mode and choose to display a message on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to make a custom wallpaper image for the lock screen.

Mine displays my name, address, email and contact numbers.

Comment: This is the simplest solution I think. I do the same.

Comment: Remember to include an extra 200px or so around the edges & make the images square [yes, really], for the '3D motion look'. I Googled for the sizes when I made mine, but still had to juggle it through photoshop a few times before I managed to avoid all the additional possibilities floating on a lock screen.